# # in SQL Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have somebody elses code (C# ASP.Net) which contains the following query:

```
string query = "SELECT distinct(destinations.name) as Destinations 
                FROM destinations, flights 
                WHERE destinations.d_ID = flights.d_ID 
                  AND flights.Date = #" + date.ToShortDateString() + "#";
```

I could not find why the # is required here before and after the date parameter. It could be passed as a normal string value (between ' and '). Is there any advantage of using # ?

Many Thanks, 
Ali

Comment: Looks like a throwback to Access & VBA syntax.  What's the DB server technology?

Comment: As a really sketchy form of protection against broken date strings? This is the kind of thing where stored procedures are your friend.

Comment: Thank You all. The database in use is MS Access.

Comment: You mean, JET/ACE. Access is not a database -- it is a database application development platform. Its default database engine is Jet/ACE, and it is this database engine that uses # as the delimiter for dates in SQL.

Comment: Nah, they probably mean MS Access as an informal contraction of 'the Microsoft Access database engine', being the collective term for ACE and Jet. But then you knew that from the context so you correction is mere pedantry -- takes one to know one ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this against an access database? That platform requires dates be bracketed by the "#"

Edit: to answer your main question, no, unless it is Access where it would be required, there is no benefit of leaving the hash marks in the query as is.

Comment: The # is not *required* for the Access database engine. For example, rather than using the DATETIME literal #7/1/2009#, you could use the text literal '2009-07-01' which would be implicitly coerced to DATETIME when evaluated. The advantage of using text is to avoid Access changing the local short date format to US (ambiguous) format.

Answer (score 10):

There is nothing wrong with the pound symbol, but it is not ANSI compliant SQL.  You are much better off rewriting the query with a parameter for the date.

```
ex:

SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT distinct(destinations.name) as Destinations FROM destinations, flights WHERE destinations.d_ID = flights.d_ID AND flights.Date = @dateparm";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("dateparm",value);
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: +1, the pound signs aren't the problem, it's the concatination that's the problem.  One thing to note: SqlClient supports named parameters, other clients may not.

Answer (score 3):

That is access syntax, are you sure you are connecting to sql server?